# In one event want to create an image and in same function want to start drag on that image

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have one imagecanvas in XAML.

```
 <Canvas Name="imgCanvas" >
                <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                    <CompositeTransform TranslateX="0" TranslateY="0" CenterX="0" CenterY="0"></CompositeTransform>
                </Canvas.RenderTransform>



            </Canvas>
```

In class constructor I m adding drag event to this canvas

```
   g = GestureService.GetGestureListener(imgCanvas);
            g.DragStarted += new EventHandler<DragStartedGestureEventArgs>(g_DragStarted);
            g.DragDelta += new EventHandler<DragDeltaGestureEventArgs>(g_DragDelta);
            g.DragCompleted += new EventHandler<DragCompletedGestureEventArgs>(g_DragCompleted);
```

Now in 1 tap function I'm creating image dynamically, and adding as a children of canvas

When tap event finished then I am able to drag that image.

Is there any way so that I can use hold type function..and instead of using tap I can use hold and in hold function only without making my mouse up I can drag it.

I try mouseleftbuttondown and mousemove event also ....but in mouse move function I m not able to drag it.

```
Ct.translateX+=e.GetPosition(layoutGrid).X;//not working

Ct.translateY+=e.GetPosition(layoutGrid).Y;
```

Please suggest to me any way so that I can add image to canvas and able to drag that in 1 tap.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this in a single event as there are two very distinct actions you want to detect and respond to.

Firstly, don't use the Gestures from the Toolkit. They are deprecated and have performance/memory issues.

You should be able to do this with the mouse events. What you'll need to do:
- After mousedown, as long as there is very little movement and no mouse up in a short period, create the image.
- After the image is created, respond to mousemove events by updating the position of the image until there is a mouse up.

There are likely to be lots of fun edge cases to handle but I'm sure you'll find them. ;)